# Data is inserted and updated using SQL queries....then why do we need doGet,post and put method

Tags: java, servlets

In http requestvwe have get, put, post,delete methods..
Post is used for insertion and
Put is used for updating.
These operations are carried out using SQL queries....then what's the point in using doGet,doPost method?

Answer (score 1):

You’re confusing two separate concepts. Http verbs are typically used as part of RESTful web services. So really, this question can be rephrased as “why do we interact with the outside world via web services rather than just giving them direct database access?”

That being the case, one of the most obvious reasons is security. It’s very hard to control how others interact with the data once they have direct access to the database - they can see data that you may not want to show them, and they can make inappropriate edits and deletions.

Also, people would have to understand your database structure as well as the the SQL variant that you’re using. The fact that I know Oracle PL/SQL doesn’t imply knowing how to use MySQL particularly well.

One final point: what makes you so sure that all RESTful services have a SQL database on their back end? Couldn’t they use Hadoop or MongoDB or something like that instead?

Either way, the database logic is an implementation detail. The HTTP verbs are a way for us to interact with each other programmatically without needing to know much about each other’s systems. I don’t care what my vendor’s database looks like - I just care how to call the endpoints they offer me.